# Spring Boot, Thymeleaf and CSS

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is really silly but I am not able to get it working.

In my spring boot mvc app, I have let's say 5 thyme leaf templates one of which is error.html.

error.html comes handy when a request is made for any invalid routes.

The issue happens when the invalid routes are nested (like 2 or more level) then the css dont apply.

Eg:

```
http://localhost:3000/application/index- valid route and css is applied
http://localhost:3000/application/success- valid route and css is applied
http://localhost:3000/application/failure- valid route and css is applied
http://localhost:3000/application/invalidroute- route does not exist but css is applied
http://localhost:3000/application/invalidroute/something - route does not exist and css is also not applied
```

My CSS is located in css folder under the static folder

All the thymeleaf templates are at the same level and access the css by

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
```

Error seen in console

```
GET http://localhost:3000/application/invalidroute/css/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
```

Use this :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
```

and make sure this is your file placeholders

`src/main/resource/static/css` - for CSS files

`src/main/resource/templates` - for HTML templates files